# mat-errors are displaying even after input fields are filled in reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am displaying some data using an `form` in an component called `edit`(displayed in dialog window).

like this image:
[image]

I am facing an issue, even after the input fields are filled. On clicking save button it's still showing warning messages like this( mt-error):

[image]

Stackbliz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-6rkey7?file=app%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.ts)

Updated [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-udqfbb?file=app/edit/edit.component.ts).

While restarting **app** through `ng-serve`, I am getting this Warings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding value in the "input" box will not update your "Form Model". Also, there is no need of `value` attribute in `inputs`. Initialize your form like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.editCusForm = this.fb.group({
        name: [this.data ? this.data.name : null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z ]+)*')]],
        age: [this.data ? this.data.age : null, [Validators.required]],
    });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-mine-r8upg6?file=app%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.ts

Comment: Working fine `stackblitz` but in `app`, Getting this warning: **[ts] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.**

Comment: In my application i am calling data from an api.

Comment: @Empty_Soul: Then you define the type of data, returned by API. Something like: `{name: string, age: string, ..other props}`. Other thing to mention. So are you creating your form after the API call is done? If not then update the form once API call is finished. Other quick/dirty fix will be accessing like: `data['name']`

Comment: I have already create an interface called  `ICustomer` in File called `model.ts`. There i have assigned datatypes `{name: string, age: string,..} `

Comment: @Empty_Soul: And still ts shows those errors?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, still it is showing error...:)

Comment: **error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.** Still the same error Continuous.

Comment: @Empty_Soul Why will it say **string** if you have the type as `Interface`? Can you update your question with your relevant actual code?

Comment: Okay, let me update with **stackblitz** link

Comment: Please see the updated **DEMO**.

Comment: Now the values(`name` to `title`, `age` to `body`) are changed because of dummy api.